# What is the general name for small machines we use at home

Tags: word-choice

How can we name the things which work with electricity like tv, kettle, hoover, iron, washing machine or ventilator at a home.

for example can we say :

home gadgets
home equipments

Comment: Home appliances.

Comment: gadgets implies smaller, more 'clever' & these days is being replaced by 'devices' for computer tablet/phone etc. For washer, fridge, cooker, there's also 'white goods'

Comment: 'white goods' seems to be a BrE usage. At least it is not an everyday usage in AmE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*appliance* is used for many things, but in everyday language, an *electronic item* is a different category.

For larger and more expensive items, such as refrigerator, washer, dryer,

home or household *appliance*

For coffee maker, toaster oven, toaster,

small *appliance* or kitchen *appliance*

**But** for television, stereo, etc,

*consumer electronic (item)*

There are many *TV and Appliance* stores, which shows the difference in category

Comment: +1, even though I'm very unlikely to refer to a TV or radio as an _appliance_. I don't know if that's a regional thing or not.

Comment: Stores sell appliances, people use 'stuff' ;)  It really is a distinction used more in the retail trade, than as a consumer.

Comment: Actually, I wouldn't either @J.R. and my original answer stated as such. So I'll edit again. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Every day we use several types of home appliance. If we introduce with room wise it would be better. Lets start with drawing room, in that we use small lighting decor,tv remote, tv, sound systems etc. Then go to the dining room there are lots of electronic appliance we can use. such as refrigerator, oven, toaster etc. Rest of the room we use washer,dryer, computer laptop, pressure cooker, blender machine, electronic hitter haire dryer, stereo and more.  Those this we customize our own interest. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [ell.se]! The author of the question isn't asking for a list of machines, just a general 'umbrella' term. I guess "home appliance" would work, but could you please [edit] your answer to make that stand out and remove the list? Please read our Help Center article [answer] for tips on how to write a good answer.